# Can I still use my Worcestershire sauce?

Tags: food-safety, sauce, seasoning

So we have this Lea&Perrins Worcestershire Sauce from the past 6-7 years ago. And I would like to really know if it is still safe to consume?

I've done my research but I'm still not sure if I could consume it because I do not know how it actually tastes.

It is kinda dusty on the top, but it was last opened years ago and it was just in our cabinet so i don't know if it is still safe to consume

Answer (score 3):

Lea & Perrins Worcestershire is shelf stable.  As long as it's been in the cupboard with the cap on, it is safe.  The flavor may have degraded, but it won't make you sick.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s quickly [check the ingredients:](https://www.leaandperrins.co.uk/our-sauce)

> - Malt Vinegar (from Barley),
>
>   - Spirit Vinegar,
>   - Molasses,
>   - Sugar,
>   - Salt,
>   - Anchovies (Fish),
>   - Tamarind Extract,
>   - Onions,
>   - Garlic,
>   - Spice,
>   - Flavourings

Note that the vinegars, the sugar, the salt will all contribute to preserving the sauce, even after opening and stored at room temperature. From a food safety perspective, it *should* be ok. Whether the sensory quality is still good is another question.

**But** we can’t see, smell or taste the sauce for you, so it’s up to you to decide, one of the rules of food safety says that if something seems “off”, discard no matter what the theory says. If you are unsure, it’s probably best to stick with the most basic rule of food safety: **When in doubt, throw it out**.